# Java Scanner specify line separator

Tags: java

I use `Scanner` class in Java for IO operation.
I want to read every line in a file that ends with "\n\r|[\r\n]", excluding other separator that may also stand for the line separator, such as "[  \u2028\2029\0085]".
If I use `Scanner.nextLine()`, these unicode separators will be included unless I change the source code of the `Scanner`.
If I use `Scanner.next("some pattern")`, the empty line will be ignored which is not what I expect.
Is there any proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the line-end characters?

Comment: @NomadMaker Each line of the file is the query from one user. It is supposed to be treated as a whole while some users input invisible characters such as \u2028.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner does not provide a way to override the pattern it uses for line endings.

However, you can achieve somerhing similar like this:

```
String line = scanner.next("[\R \u2028\u2029\u0085]");
```

and use `scanner.hasNext("[\R\u2028\u2029\u0085]")` instead of `scanner.hasNextLine()`.

Note: `\R` was introduced in version 8 and means any flavour of "line end" character sequence (ie `\r\n`, `\n` or `\r` which works for windows, *nix and mac)

Comment: ```scanner.hasNext()``` will skip blank line automatically, I'm afraid.

Comment: @luoshao23 OK. Try edited answer. If that doesn't work, please tell me the char sequence you want it to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I read @Bohemian answer and I believe that you can achieve this easily. Since java 8 you have the two functions `useDelimiter` and `delimiter`. These functions allow you to define your delimiter and check its value. In this case you want '\r' or '\n', etc. Then you can use simply `hasNext` and `next` simply:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
sc.useDelimiter("\n");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String line =  sc.next();
}
```

This code snippet logic rhymes well with the description given in the java 8 [Scanner documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.